# Trying to login to linkedin with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to login into linkedin with python requests. I keep getting an error saying that I "Must be authorized to access this page". I usually use requests for `get` and not the `post` methods. I want to use this to make it much faster to login.

My code is below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com'
payload = {"session_key": 'ENTER EMAIL', "session_password": 'Enter Password'}
page = requests.post(url, data=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Comment: Well, is this exactly what your browser does while logging you in? Are you using the exact same method (POST), passing the appropriate headers and the appropriate parameters?

Comment: I haven’t checked that out. I’ll give that a look first. Thanks.

Comment: i have tried to post different user/pd on browser,then i find it need website's javascrip to create some data which is dynamic,You better use selenuim

Comment: try replacing `data=payload` with `json=payload`.

Comment: @Fozoro didn't work. :(